# Ubuntu 14.04 crashes when running a project in Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, ubuntu-14.04, java-6

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2. When I try to run a project, the whole system crashes (and I don't get any errors)

```
dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
```

gives

```
ii  default-jdk                                           2:1.7-51                                            amd64        Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit
ii  default-jdk-doc                                       0.51                                                all          Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit (documentation)
ii  openjdk-7-doc                                         7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1                         all          OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
ii  openjdk-7-jdk:amd64                                   7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2                         amd64        OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ii  openjdk-7-jre:amd64                                   7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2                         amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64                          7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2                         amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  oracle-java8-installer                                8u51+8u51arm-1~webupd8~0                            all          Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 8
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: more suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Does it happen when you run any project, or a specific project? Why do you think the problem is related to the distro or JDK installation?

Comment: I have a simple Main class, and a simple GUI. 
when I try to create a new instance of GUI it crashes. I tried to simply write `System.out.println("abc");` without instantiating GUI class and works fine.

Comment: worth to check X server logs after a crash. I don't see how jvm could crash system, but if netbeans has some native UI hooks to X, then graphics driver could crash.